# JQuery add opening of a div to element, then close div after different element

Tags: html, jquery

I have looked through jquery documentation and every example I've tried causes issues for me. I have a bunch of list items with different classes, I'd simply like to add a div () before one particular li item.

Then I'd like to target a different list item and add a closing div ().

When I have tried this using prependTo and append etc but none of them are working as they automatically close the div I have opened. My code so far looks like this:

```
<ul>
<li class="textbox email">This is the email list item</li>
<li class="textbox address">This is the address list item</li>
<li class="textbox aboutme">This is the aboutme list item</li>
</ul>
```

and I would like it to come out as:

```
<ul>
<li class="textbox email">This is the email list item</li>
<div class="open"> <!-- div id opened here -->
<li class="textbox address">This is the address list item</li>
<li class="textbox aboutme">This is the aboutme list item</li>
</div> <!-- div is closed here -->
</ul>
```

Currently, if I try:

```
 $("<div>").prependTo(".email");//prependTo append at inside top
```

The output will automatically close the div as such:

```
<ul>
<div></div> <!-- div closed automatically instead of remaining open -->
<li class="textbox email">This is the email list item</li>
<li class="textbox address">This is the address list item</li>
<li class="textbox aboutme">This is the aboutme list item</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: `<ul>` can only contain `<li>` elements, you're attempting to create invalid html

Comment: Did you try wrap() function? http://api.jquery.com/wrap/

Comment: What you probably want is to include another `ul` for the first option. This is valid html: `<ul>
<li class="textbox email">This is the email list item
<ul class="open">
<li class="textbox address">This is the address list item</li>
<li class="textbox aboutme">This is the aboutme list item</li>
</ul></li>
</ul>`

Comment: Ok I've used this code $(".email").after("<ul>").nextAll("li").appendTo($(".email").next()); so its valid HTML and an extra UL can be used for my accordion

Comment: No, no, that does not generate valid markup. Pay attention to the first `li`. The close tag for the first `li` is at end, ie, the first  `li` is the parent of sub `ul`, not the sibling. Again, compare the output of your expression against my comment above

Answer (score 3):

Garry, sorry but you got it wrong.

Your solution `$(".email").after("<ul>").nextAll("li").appendTo($(".email").next());` creates **invalid markup**:

```
<ul>
    <li class="textbox email">This is the email list item</li>
    <ul>
        <li class="textbox address">This is the address list item</li>
        <li class="textbox aboutme">This is the aboutme list item</li>
    </ul>
</ul>
```

because the `ul` elements can only contain child `li` elements. In this case, the outer `ul` has one `li` and one `ul` child,  which is semantically invalid.

---

What you want is this:

```
<ul>
    <li class="textbox email">This is the email list item
        <ul>
            <li class="textbox address">This is the address list item</li>
            <li class="textbox aboutme">This is the aboutme list item</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

This is **valid markup** since both `ul` elements have only `li` children, and `li` can have other `ul` inside. In other words, the outer `ul` has only one child (email) that contains itself another `ul` list.

So, the code to generate the valid markup above is

```
// get the .address and .aboutme and wrap a UL around these two LIs
$(".email").nextAll("li").wrapAll("<ul class='open'>"); 

// move the recently created UL.open to the .email
$(".email").append($(".open"));
```

or if you prefer all in one statment, something like this:

```
$(".email").nextAll("li").wrapAll("<ul class='open'>").parent().prev(".email").append($(".open"));
```

Answer (score 3):

There is example to Wrap a div using HTML

```
<div class="container">
 <div class="selector">Hello</div>
 </div>
```

And The JS Is

```
$( ".selector" ).wrap( "<div class='yourClass'></div>" );
```

and HTML will be changed AS

```
 <div class="container">
  <div class='yourClass'>
   <div class="selector">Hello</div>
  </div>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You're attempting to create invalid html, however if you *really* want to, you need to move the `<li>` elements into the div rather than adding opening and closing tags. Due to the invalid nature of the html however, there may be some inconsistent behaviour across browsers.

Answer (score 0):

You must know that these jQuery append and prepend are operations that work on DOM tree, so you can't simply modify it in that way.

Also putting `<div>` inside `<ul>` is wrong.

Please write what you're trying to achieve, maybe it can be done other way.

Comment: The whole reason I'm trying to do this is because we don't have access to the code via ftp so I have to manipulate the dom with jquery. I need to be able to wrap certain list items in an element, that I can then add the accordion effect to when a link is clicked. I'm basically working with a form which has each field inside list items, so I want to wrap a div around the majority of the list items and hide it, and they show these when they click a link that reads "click here to give us more information" - I gathered adding a div around these list items then performing some show/hide would work